# Given that the first of the month is a monday, define a predicate to print the day for any date in a month using list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

This way actually worked. But are there any simplified answer.

```
dayname(Num,Name) :-
    member([Num,Name],
           [[1,'Monday'],[2,'Tuesday'],[3,'Wednesday'],[4,'Thursday'],
            [5,'Friday'],[6,'Saturday'],[7,'Sunday'],[8,'Monday'],
            [9,'Tuesday'],[10,'Wednesday'],[11,'Thursday'],[12,'Friday'],
            [13,'Saturday'],[14,'Sunday'],[15,'Monday'],[16,'Tuesday'],
            [17,'Wednesday'],[18,'Thursday'],[19,'Friday'],[20,'Saturday'],
            [21,'Sunday'],[22,'Monday'],[23,'Tuesday'],[24,'Wednesday'],
            [25,'Thursday'],[26,'Friday'],[27,'Saturday'],[28,'Sunday'],
            [29,'Monday'],[30,'Tuesday'],[31,'Monday']]).
```

Comment: Sounds like homework...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. First of all you **do not need to use `member/2`** for facts. You can list these as facts:

```
dayname(1,'Monday').
dayname(2,'Tuesday').
dayname(3,'Wednesday').
dayname(4,'Thursday').
dayname(5,'Friday').
dayname(6,'Saturday').
dayname(7,'Sunday').
```

But now we have of course no way to obtain `'Monday'` for 8. Probably the most declarative way to do this is the following clause:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

dayname(I,D) :-
    I in 8..31,
    J #= I-7,
    dayname(J,D).
```

Putting this all together, we get:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

dayname(1,'Monday').
dayname(2,'Tuesday').
dayname(3,'Wednesday').
dayname(4,'Thursday').
dayname(5,'Friday').
dayname(6,'Saturday').
dayname(7,'Sunday').
dayname(I,D) :-
    I in 8..31,
    J #= I-7,
    dayname(J,D).
```

We then query it in all possible ways:

```
?- dayname(I,D).
I = 1,
D = 'Monday' ;
I = 2,
D = 'Tuesday' ;
I = 3,
D = 'Wednesday' ;
I = 4,
D = 'Thursday' ;
I = 5,
D = 'Friday' ;
I = 6,
D = 'Saturday' ;
I = 7,
D = 'Sunday' ;
I = 8,
D = 'Monday' ;
I = 9,
D = 'Tuesday' ;
I = 10,
D = 'Wednesday' ;
I = 11,
D = 'Thursday' ;
I = 12,
D = 'Friday' ;
I = 13,
D = 'Saturday' ;
I = 14,
D = 'Sunday' ;
I = 15,
D = 'Monday' ;
I = 16,
D = 'Tuesday' ;
I = 17,
D = 'Wednesday' ;
I = 18,
D = 'Thursday' ;
I = 19,
D = 'Friday' ;
I = 20,
D = 'Saturday' ;
I = 21,
D = 'Sunday' ;
I = 22,
D = 'Monday' ;
I = 23,
D = 'Tuesday' ;
I = 24,
D = 'Wednesday' ;
I = 25,
D = 'Thursday' ;
I = 26,
D = 'Friday' ;
I = 27,
D = 'Saturday' ;
I = 28,
D = 'Sunday' ;
I = 29,
D = 'Monday' ;
I = 30,
D = 'Tuesday' ;
I = 31,
D = 'Wednesday' ;
false.

?- dayname(15,D).
D = 'Monday' ;
false.

?- dayname(I,'Thursday').
I = 4 ;
I = 11 ;
I = 18 ;
I = 25 ;
false.

?- dayname(12,'Thursday').
false.

?- dayname(11,'Thursday').
true ;
false.
```

Comment: but, i need to use the list function.

Comment: @kratos_krom: In that case I suggest you do the homework yourself :)